# Cloud9 - Open new terminal from command line

Tags: cloud9-ide

I created one script which will start my application and other services in another terminal but it is not working

I tried **gnome-terminal** but command not found error showing

```
#!/bin/sh
mongod
gnome-terminal -e ./setup/elasticsearch-2.2.0/bin/elasticsearch
```

**Edit :**

```
#!/bin/sh
mongod & 
bash ./setup/elasticsearch-2.2.0/bin/elasticsearch & 
cd ./project/movie/
node server.js
```

Because of background process at 2 line elasticsearch starting and then 3 and 4 line is executed and at 4 line elastic search is not started it is in starting process actually so my node will throw the error

{ [Error: No Living connections] message: 'No Living connections' }

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
mongod > mongo.log 2>mongoerror.log &
bash ./setup/elasticsearch-2.2.0/bin/elasticsearch
```

[gnome-terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Terminal) is not installed, which makes sense because [Gnome](https://www.gnome.org/) (the Desktop Environment) is not either.
In order to run elasticsearch you can use bash (which is what is running by default on c9.io )

Also I have changed mongod line to write logs and error logs to two files and run in the background, you can remove that if you want, but elastic search will run after mongod finishes.

You can do the same thing with the elastic search line as well.